# Type map apachesoap unresolved

Tags: xml, apache, xsd, wsdl

I'm meeting a problem with a WSDL file I've imported.
In this file, the map type is used from the namespace : xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"

But it is unresolved... When I try to go to this URL, I get a "404 error not found"

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `namespace` value is not necessarily a document. The document carrying the namespaced elements can be given either during an import/ include or either with the attribute `schemaLocation`

cf. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#sec-namespaces

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't know why you said that :/ ?

Comment: This WSDL file must be itself importing other files, one of them is defining the `http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap` namespace. Can you find this file ? A file defining `targetnamespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"` in its schema tag

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue. Did you find a solution? @Ranpie49

Answer (score 0):

In the WSDL I've imported, we can read that :

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <import namespace="http://exception.metier.framework.civitas.fr" /> 
    <import namespace="Boite_A_Tache" /> 
    <import namespace="http://srvcegid01:8080/gfprod/services/Boite_A_Tache" /> 
    <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" /> 
    <complexType name="mapItem">
        <sequence>
            <element name="key" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType" /> 
            <element name="value" nillable="true" type="xsd:anyType" /> 
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <complexType name="Map">
        <sequence>
            <element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" type="apachesoap:mapItem" /> 
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

The type "Map" is well defined.
Nevertheless, the software I'm using (Websphere Message Broker d'IBM), makes some transformations on WSDL file.

You can see a little part of the WSDL "modified" :

```
<wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:appinfo source="WMQI_APPINFO">
        <MRWSDLAppInfo imported="true">
            <generatedXSD location="blablabla_1_InlineSchema1.xsd"/>
            <generatedXSD location="blablabla_1_InlineSchema2.xsd"/>
            <generatedXSD location="blablabla_1_InlineSchema3.xsd"/>
            <generatedXSD location="blablabla_1_InlineSchema4.xsd"/>
            <binding hasEncoding="true" imported="true" name="BlablaSoapBinding" originalBindingStyle="rpc"/>
            <generatedXSD location="blablabla_1.wsdl"/>
         </MRWSDLAppInfo>
     </wsdl:appinfo>
</wsdl:documentation>

<wsdl:types>
    <schema targetNamespace="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import namespace="http://bla.bla.bla.fr"/>
        <import namespace="blabla"/>
        <import namespace="http://blabla:8080/blabla/blabla/blabla"/>
        <xsd:include schemaLocation="blabla1_InlineSchema1.xsd"/>
    </schema>
     ....
    (autres schemas)
<wsdl:types>
```